# How to check text is not present in the list

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I want to check if the text is not present in the list.

```
this.TenantList = element.all(by.repeater("tenant in tenantList"));
expect(TenantList.getAttribute('aria-label'))not().toContain('Test');
```

I tried following but its failing : `is not a function`

```
 expect(TenantList.getAttribute('aria-label'))not().toContain('Test');
 expect(TenantList.getAttribute('aria-label').toContain('Test')).toBe(false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.not` is not a function, the correct syntax is:

```
expect(TenantList.getAttribute('aria-label')).not.toContain('Test');
```